# Force Usernames in Ex2K3 Public Folder Calendars

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

We are running a Win2K3 domain with a single Exchange 2003 server. We have a few public folders set up with calendars which people can use to book things like meeting rooms or loan equipment. The problem we have is that people often book things on behalf of others and or put the event they are booking it for as the subject rather than their own name. Is there a way to force this calendar entry to put their name as the subject, and lock it down so that they cannot change it? Or is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative for booking resources (rooms/equipment) in Exchange 2003 is to create a user mailbox for the room and then set the acceptance rules and lock it down so they can't directly book it from the actual calendar.

An example is found here along with other "choices":

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Booking-Resources-ExchangeServer-2003-Outlook-System-2003.html

Honestly, I've never liked how Ex2k3 did it.  I like the way Ex2k7 does it much better with actual Resource Mailboxes.